# How to revert keyboard layout switching shortcuts after setting them with xkb's /etc/default/keyboard XKBOPTION in Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, xkb

I wanted to have two keyboard layouts (one for english and one for spanish), and add a shortcut for switching between them.

The solution I chose was to set the following lines in my `/etc/default/keyboard` file:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,es"
XKBOPTION="grp:ctrl_shift_toggle"
```

This has turned out to be a mistake because the ctrl_shift shortcut interfers and takes precedence over all other application level shortcuts like browser's ctrl+shift+tab and vi's ctrl+shift+insert.

I haven't found a way to revert this change and have it persist in between shutdowns.

Here are the methods I have tried:
1) Removing the `XKBOPTION` line from `/etc/default/keyboard`
2) Running the command `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard`
3) Running the command `setxkbmap -option`. This works but is reset upon restarting.
4) Configuring one single layout by adding the line `XKBLAYOUT` and adding the alternative layout via GNOME and using the GNOME shortcut (Super space). The switch has no effect and is reset upon restarting.

I don't know where these changes are stored in between installs, I have ran grep with searching for terms like XKBOPTION,ctrl_shift_toggle but I can't seem to find it. All I can find is that the `setxkbmap -print` command shows the ctrl_shift_toggle option:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+es:2+us:3+inet(evdev)+grp(ctrl_shift_toggle)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

However, as mentioned, I cannot find the file responsible for the ctrl_shift_toggle configuration.

Note: The question is looking for an answer that can revert the state of the keyboard setting either to the original setting, or to the desired configuration. Reinstalling the OS or a solution that starts from a clean install is not considered an optimal solution. The reason for this is that, as a superuser, I want to have deep control of my system.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is the possibility that I A) have a bug specific to my configuration or B) modified another setting through a file or command that I can't remember. So I would appreciate if someone with guts could try to reproduce this bug in their computer, or if someone with time/virtual machine skills could try it in a discardable sandbox. I expect this bug to occur in a clean Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Thank you!

Comment: I still have this problem after 5 months. Maybe it's time to reinstall the whole OS, or even better, change OS

Comment: Does [trhis solution](https://superuser.com/a/867693/8672) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Run setxkbmap -option on startup every time. Adding the line to rc.local doesn't work for some reason.

This solution doesn't undo the original configuration, but rather overwrites it.